# Error: list indices must be integers not float

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code following should take the list of marks from the dictionary of a student and calculate the average marks of the student. I am getting the "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float" error.

```
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}

# Averege function is given below for calculating avg
def average(lst):
    l=float(len(lst))
    total = 0.0
    #code works till here the error occoured below
    for item in lst:
        add = int(lst[item])
        print add
        total+=add
    return total//l

print average(alice['tests'])
print alice['tests']
```

Comment: Why are you averaging tyler?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus How can you average Tyler? *He's [imaginary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137523/)!*

Comment: Sry abt that, I gave an sample entry named alice instead of tyler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is on this line:

```
for item in lst:
    add = int(lst[item])
```

`for item in lst` Iterates through each `item` in the list, not an index. So `item` is the value of the float in the list.
Instead try this:

```
for item in lst:
    add = int(item)
```

Additionally, there is no reason to cast to an integer as this will mess with your average, so you can shorten it further to:

```
for item in lst:
    add = item
```

Which means the for loop can be shortened to just:

```
for item in lst:
    total+= item
```

Which means we can shorten it even further, using the [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) built in:

```
total = sum(lst)
```

Since `total` is now a float, we don't need to specify float division using the double slash, and we no longer need to cast the length to a float, so the function becomes:

```
def average(lst):
    l=len(lst)
    total = sum(lst)
    return total/l
```

And lastly, there is no reason to not do this all on one easy to read line:

```
def average(lst):
    return sum(lst)/len(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it was really helpful in reducing the length of the code. I'll certainly use this approach

Answer (score 3):

The `for item in lst` will let `item` get each and every item in `lst` on each iteration. So, change

```
add = int(lst[item])
```

to

```
add = int(item)
```

For example, try this to understand better

```
data = ["a", "b", "c"]
for char in data:
    print char
```

will print

```
a
b
c
```

If you ever wanted to get the current index of the item, then you can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function

```
data = ["a", "b", "c"]
for index, char in enumerate(data):
    print index, char, data[index]
```

**Output**

```
0 a a
1 b b
2 c c
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, it worked. I was thinking of the traditional for(i=0,,i++) loop while writing the code. thanks for letting me know its a wrong approach.